# ui-serf attribute is automatic rename in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I write simple code for understanding ui-router of angular js but code is working properly but my partial html code is automatic renaming, i am unable to undertable why it happing

Html code is   `<a ui-sref="state1.list">Show List</a>`

and browser code is `<a ui-sref="state.list" class="ng-scope">Show List</a>` due to rename the state1 to state my another partial view is not calling and give error.

Please take a look

```html
<!--index.html-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Angular UI Router Test </title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a ui-sref="state1"> State 1</a>
    <div ui-view></div>
    <script>
        var module = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
        module.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/state1');
            $stateProvider
                .state('state1', {
                    url: '/state1',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/state1.html'
                })
            .state('state1.list', {
                url: '/list',
                templateUrl: 'partials/state1.list.html',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
                }
            });
        }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!--state1.html-->

<h1>State 1</h1>
<hr />

<a ui-sref="state1.list">Show List</a>
    
<div ui-view></div>
```

```html
<!--state1.list.html-->

<h3>List of State 1 Items</h3>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

what i am missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, you are most likely not observing the proper element. I [created working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lVPhWEB7jGtioiefRtWw?p=preview) here, and it shows, that this:

```
<a ui-sref="state1.list">Show List</a>
```

is generated as this

```
<a ui-sref="state1.list" class="ng-scope" href="#/state1/list">Show List</a>
```

As we can see no change from  `state1.list` into `state.list`

The biggest change made? - **used are up to date angular and UI-Router versions**

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lVPhWEB7jGtioiefRtWw?p=preview), and maybe try to reset it to the "wrong state described above"

Comment: Hi Radim, I saw your code its working on pluker. I am upate my angular and ui-router js references as your plunker code but problem is same again.I insert browser image above.

Comment: Could you update my plunker to reproduce the issue?. Because, what you describe is hardly to happen. Or give me more details... because as my plunker shows... it will "never" happen. My plunker is working as expected

Comment: Simply, this `<a ui-sref="state.list" class="ng-scope">Show List</a>` I could achieve only if I wrongly spell this: `<a ui-sref="state.list">Show List</a>`. Check it here http://plnkr.co/edit/Pivk7QxUcP5ohccskEF2?p=preview. So, only if I use ui-sref="state.list" I recieve your results. Please, try to recheck your own code

Comment: I upload my code in https://www.dropbox.com/s/dsrumyeu9qjc3by/UI-Router.zip?dl=0 link download from here

Comment: Thanks, you was right there spelling misstake now code is working properly

Comment: Great! Enjoy ui-router :)